# Divergence theorem involving continuously differentiable function

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, divergence-theorem

> Question: Let $\gamma \colon [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}^2$ be so that it is continuous and piecewise differentiable and defines a simple closed graph on $\mathbb{R}^2$ that encloses a bounded open connected set $\Omega$. Let $u$ be continuously differentiable on an open connected set that contains the closure of $\Omega$. Show that there exists a function on the path of $\gamma$, defined as $v \colon \gamma([0,1]) \to \mathbb{R}^2$ so that
> $$\int_\Omega \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} d A = \int_{\partial \Omega} u(\sigma) \cdot v (\sigma) \, d \sigma.$$ Hence, show that there exists $c_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ with $|c_0| = 1$ so that
> $$\int_\Omega \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} d A = c_0 \int_0^1 u(\gamma(t)) \gamma_2'(t) \, dt$$ where $\gamma(t) = (\gamma_1(t), \gamma_2(t))$.

My attempt: For the first part, it seems like a direct application of divergence theorem, but I don't understand why should the normal vector be defined on the path of $\gamma$. As for the second part, I am unsure how to make the change of variable. Any hints are appreciated.

Comment: How many dimensions has $u$ and what is $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\,?$ In the divergence theorem as we know it the normal vector is defined on $\partial\Omega$ which is the path of your $\gamma\,.$

Comment: $u$ is a $2$-variable function. So, $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(x,y)$.

Comment: $u$ also has to have two components $u_1$ and $u_2$ otherwise that dot product $u(\sigma)\cdot v(\sigma)$ does not make sense. Which component of $u$ is it that we differentiate in $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\,?$

Comment: @KurtG. you are right. This question seems to have the wrong notation. Is there any way to rectify this issue?

Comment: Not for the second task, at least not for me. The author of the question has to rectify this. The whole question is weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gauss' divergence theorem says
\begin{align}
\int_\Omega{\rm div}\,\mathbf{u}\,dA&=\int_\Omega\partial_x u_1+\underbrace{\partial_yu_2}_{(*)}\,dA=\oint_{\partial\Omega}\mathbf{u}\cdot\mathbf{n}\,d\sigma\\
&=\int_0^1-\underbrace{u_1(\gamma(t))\,\dot\gamma_2(t)}_{(**)}+u_2(\gamma(t))\,\dot\gamma_1(t)\,dt\,.\tag{1}
\end{align}
where we use the fact that the normal vector $\mathbf{n}$ at $\partial \Omega$
is perpendicular to the tangent $\dot\gamma\,,$ hence parallel to
$$
\begin{pmatrix}-\dot\gamma_2\\\dot\gamma_1\end{pmatrix}\,.
$$
Green's theorem says
$$\tag{2}
\int_\Omega\partial_xu_2-\partial_yu_1\,dA=\oint_{\partial\Omega}\mathbf{u}\cdot\,d\mathbf{s}=
\int_0^1u_1(\gamma(t))\,\dot\gamma_1(t)+u_2(\gamma(t))\,\dot\gamma_2(t)\,dt\,.
$$
If we apply Green's theorem to $(u_2,u_1)$ instead of $\mathbf{u}$
we get
\begin{align}\tag{3}
\int_\Omega \partial_xu_1-\underbrace{\partial_yu_2}_{(*)}\,dA=\int_0^1u_2(\gamma(t))\,\dot\gamma_1(t)+\underbrace{u_1(\gamma(t))\,\dot\gamma_2(t)}_{(**)}\,dt\,.
\end{align}
Adding (1) and (3) and cancelling the underbraced terms with opposite signs gives
$$\tag{4}
\int_\Omega\partial_xu_1\,dA=\int_0^1u_2(\gamma(t))\,\dot\gamma_1(t)\,dt=\int_{\partial \Omega}\mathbf{u}\cdot\mathbf{v}\,d\sigma
$$
where
$$
\mathbf{v}=\begin{pmatrix}0\\\dot\gamma_1\end{pmatrix}
$$ is the projection of the normal $\mathbf{n}$ at $\partial \Omega$ onto the $y$-axis. This solves the first task.

Comment: Do you mind sharing how you obtain equation (4)?

Comment: I am -as I said- adding equations (1) and (3) by which the term carrying $u_2\dot \gamma_2$ cancels out. Same for the term on the LHS that integrates $\partial_yu_2\,.$

Comment: Sorry, I meant how do you show that $\int_{\partial \Omega} u \cdot d   s + \int_{\partial \Omega} u \cdot n \, d \sigma = 2 \int_{\partial \Omega}  u\ \cdot  v \, d \sigma$.

Comment: First I noticed a sign error in my version of Gauss' and Green's theorem that I was able to fix. Then I highlighted the terms that cancel with $\underbrace{\phantom{\quad}}\,.$ You wrote in OP that this is a direct application of the divergence theorem which sounded a piece of cake for you. Was it not?

Comment: I initially thought that $u$ was a function in $\mathbb{R}$ so $\nu$ is just the normal vector on the surface $\partial \Omega$. But as u pointed out, $u$ should be a function in both $x$ and $y$.

Comment: Thank you so much for the solution!